# How do I use python to read a serial value from the serial port of a Cardinal Scale head?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

If I use Putty to connect with serial to COM1, 1200 baud I get a black screen but when I type Ctlr-E on the keyboard I get the value that I'm looking to record.  If I use serial.tools.miniterm and I type Ctrl-E on the keyboard I get the proper value.  When I use the following code it seems as though I connect and there is nothing waiting in the buffer:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='com1',\
    baudrate=1200,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)
        
print(ser.flush())
print(ser.flushInput())
print(ser.reset_input_buffer())
print(ser.flushOutput())
print(ser.reset_output_buffer())
print(ser.in_waiting)
print(ser.out_waiting)
print(ser.readline())
print(ser.read())
print(ser.read(1))
    
ser.close()
```

I get back on screen:
None
None
None
None
0
0
b''
b''
b''

I was expecting one of these results to be the value I get in Putty and Miniterm.

What am I doing wrong?  After connecting with Python can I send that same key sequence that is sent by Putty when I type Ctrl-E?

Comment: It will be easier to get advice and answers if you add the vendor, model number, programming manual, etc. of the cardinal scale head you are going to use.

Comment: It's a Cardinal 210 unit and I don't have a programming manual for it.  I can connect with COM1, 1200,8,N,1.

Comment: You can find these by searching. Is it one of them? [210 Storm](https://cardinalscale.com/product/product-overview/Weight-Indicators/210-Storm), [Resouces Home Products Weight-Indicators 210 Storm](https://cardinalscale.com/resources/brochures/210-Storm?category=Weight-Indicators&category-name=Weight%20Indicators), https://cardinalscale.com/themes/ee/site/default/asset/img/resources/resources_brochures/8200-M411-O1_210-215_ADD.pdf , https://cardinalscale.com/themes/ee/site/default/asset/img/resources/resources_brochures/8200-M585-O1_210_USB.pdf

Comment: Using Putty, the scale responds when you send control-E, is that right? Your code doesn’t send control-E, or anything, so I’m not sure why you’re expecting the scale to send something - have you tried getting your code to send control-E? Try sending ‘\x05’

Comment: Looks like this is the serial interface spec https://scalemanufacturers.org/PDF/ScaleCommProtocol5199M1.pdf - the 210 is level #2 - looks like you if you send W the scale will respond with a weight.

Comment: I tried print(ser.write('\x05') and I tried print(ser.write('W') and I get "unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes".

Comment: I guess I'm saying that I don't know how to "send" a '\x05' or a 'W'.  I feel like I'm close.

Comment: serial.Serial() does not support using "send" as in ser.send('x05') so as was mentioned my code doesn't send anything.  I'm not sure how to send an echo or a W with the code I'm using.  Should I be using serial_rx_tx?  I'm looking to capture the value at the scale and write it to a database.

Comment: Read the documentation https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html  Use `.write()`

Comment: I have been trying to use write().  Each time I get just a 1 back as a response to ser.write('W'.encode('utf-8)) or ser.write('\x05'.encode('utf-8').  I've poured through the documentation.  I can reproduce the results I want from other serial devices that have information waiting like the console port of a cisco firewall.

Comment: If pySerial is not the appropriate coding language for my project perhaps someone could suggest another a programming language that I can use to behave like Putty or MiniTerm to capture the weight value from this scale.  I have read through and tried everything I could come up with along with barny's suggestion and have had no luck.. Thank you.

Comment: I am still not sure what to do here.  I have a ticket opened with the manufacturer but this thing is old and I'm not sure they are going to be too helpful.  I have nine of these scale heads all running and attached to giant truck scales using a Novell 3.12 server at each location and text-based menu system that reads the scale and writes a text file.  Now I'm just trying to do it on a Windows 10 machine.  I'm making the connection and I'm using .write() to send data to the open port but I get no response with python and serial.Serial().

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was needed / missing partially due to a post from here on Oct 2nd, 2013 by Chaosphere2112.  I need to both send an encapsulated \x05 (thanks barny) but also wait and then read the value in the buffer.

here is the code that worked in the end:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='com1',\
    baudrate=1200,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
    timeout=0)

ser.write('\x05'.encode('utf-8'))
time.sleep(1)
read_val = ser.read(size=64)
if read_val != '':
    print(read_val)
ser.close()
```

Thank you.